# Load balancing inconsistencies & AD server causing network crawl

Tags: active-directory, load-balancing, windows-terminal-services, round-robin

We've configured a TS load balancing farm consisting of the Active Directory server which acts as the TS Broker and 6 Terminal Servers who are members of the farm.  The load balancing is set to basic DNS round robin and is accessed via a common gateway also on the AD server.

We've noticed that the load balancing component appears very inconsistent to the point of non-functional.  We often have 60  users logged to a single Terminal Server, 20 or 30 on another and a majority of the servers with no load whatsoever.

When this behavior occurs we are able to access all Terminal Servers and the Gateway equally but don't know what is making the load balancing distribute the way it does. Perhaps something AD related?

Does anyone have any thoughts/suggestions on proper configurations/weights? This is standard Server 2008 R2 hosted on a bochs hypervisor.

Appreciate the insight!

Comment: Have you configured the Terminal Servers to be part of a farm with a session broker?

Comment: Personally I'd be using NLB instead of DNS Round Robin.

Comment: Yes, I do believe that the terminal servers are configured with a session broker. It wasn't my call to use Round Robin vs. NLB though.

Comment: I'd recommend you go through this step-by-step checklist: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753891.aspx - as it pretty much describes your setup. Go through the steps and verify that your current configuration matches what you expect - btw, you keep calling it TS, but as of 2008 R2, Terminal Services have been renamed to Remote Desktop Services. You're sure there are no 2008 (non-R2) servers in the mix here?

Comment: Thanks for the checklist, I'll go through it and compare our config to make sure something wasn't missed. And yeah, I know it was renamed to RDS (old habits die hard). All of the servers in the mix are 2008 R2.